# Conexão JDBC com MySQL

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou aprendendo a desenvolver java e estou tentando avançar em meus estudos para entender como fazer uma conexão com banco de dados, porém está havendo algum problema que não estou conseguindo identificar.

Abaixo o erro escrito no log:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Eu criei um pacote `br.com.ConexaoBanco` que dentro existe um arquivo `ConexaoMySQL`, o pacote eu descrevo a classe que efetua a conexão. Logo abaixo o exemplo dela.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.ConexaoBanco;

/**
 *
 * @author hotsystems
 */
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConexaoMySQL {

    public static String status = "Não conectou...";

    public ConexaoMySQL() {

    }

    public static java.sql.Connection getConexaoMySQL() {

        Connection connection = null;          //atributo do tipo Connection

        try {

            String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

            Class.forName(driverName);

            String serverName = "";    

            String mydatabase ="";       

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;

            String username = "";          

            String password = "";      

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            //Testa sua conexão//  
            if (connection != null) {

                status = ("STATUS--->Conectado com sucesso!");

            } else {

                status = ("STATUS--->Não foi possivel realizar conexão");

            }

            return connection;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  

            System.out.println("O driver do banco de dados nao foi encontrado.");

            return null;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Nao foi possivel conectar ao Banco de Dados.");

            return null;

        }

    }

    public static String statusConection() {

        return status;

    }

    public static boolean FecharConexao() {

        try {

            ConexaoMySQL.getConexaoMySQL().close();

            return true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            return false;

        }

    }

    public static java.sql.Connection ReiniciarConexao() {

        FecharConexao();

        return ConexaoMySQL.getConexaoMySQL();

    }

}
```

Na classe main, tenho um pacote `controlesincronismo` que descrevo o main do programa, a seguir o exemplo dele.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controlesincronismo;

import br.com.ConexaoBanco.ConexaoMySQL;

/**
 *
 * @author hotsystems
 */
public class ControleSincronismo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConexaoMySQL con = new ConexaoMySQL();
        con.getConexaoMySQL();
        con.statusConection();
    }

}
```

Erro:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:339)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at br.com.ConexaoBanco.ConexaoMySQL.getConexaoMySQL(ConexaoMySQL.java:81)
    at controlesincronismo.ControleSincronismo.main(ControleSincronismo.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
    ... 16 more
```

Qual tem sido meu erro ? E gostaria de saber também se estas sãos as melhores praticas para me proporcionar segurança.

Agradeço a colaboração.

Comment: Você está colocando a porta do servidor também?

Comment: Não, precisa ? Porque no PHP deu so coloco meu link no caso é 127.0.0.1

Comment: Tenta colocar assim para ver se funciona: jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/databasename

Comment: @adelmo00 qual é a porta padrão ?

Comment: o  padrão é 3306

Comment: deu um erro muito maluco, Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34966/discussion-between-adelmo00-and-renan-rodrigues).

Answer (score 2):

Eu não posso comentar ainda aí estou colocando uma resposta 
Você precisa informar o IP e o nome do banco de dados na string de conexão, como o amigo @JeuCasulo disse vai ficar algo assim, aqui funciona.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:porta/nome_banco
```

Recomendo a apostila de Java Web da caelum ela e bem clara.
https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/bancos-de-dados-e-jdbc/

Answer (score 2):

Consegui identificar o problema, na verdade estava tentando conectar a um servidor na minha maquina, em minha pergunta utilizei como parâmetro o `PHP`, porém o `PHP` funcionava pois ele o main está na maquina onde estava o servidor, e por este motivo funcionava.

A solução foi trocar o `127.0.0.1` para o endereço remoto de minha maquina. Então bastou trocar para que funciona-se o programa.

Answer (score 0):

Seu serverName e myDataBase estão vazios, ele não vai direcionar pra "lugar nenhum" assim, e seu login e senha do mySql também, você deixou em branco no workbench?

Comment: Amigo eu deixei vazio, pois não quis informar estas informações. Estou colocando os mesmo dados que coloquei na aplicação que ja está funcionando em PHP. Então provavelmente não seja estes dados.

Comment: Faz sentido, desculpe a desatenção, eu atentaria a essas strings pois qualquer detalhe vai resultar em comportamento inesperado, esse erro atualmente é comum quando o mySql não esta rodando ou quando o firewall ta bloqueando a porta ou erro no endereço, comigo era sempre o endereço mesmo